# What is the URL of this tortoise svn repository?

Tags: php, tortoisesvn

Using TortoiseSVN, I created a "repository" folder in htdocs directory (Apache web server and PHP). Opened repo-browser Included some files into it. The local URL is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/repository/project
```

Now I wanna checkout files into a working folder. When I try to provide URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/repository/project`, it doesn't work ?

This is the first time I am using URL (http://). 
Previously i have been using file:// successfully. Also have used VisualSVN (for http://) but doing it with Tortoise directly, seems a better idea for me.

Comment: Is it even possible to serve SVN through http and without WebDAV?

Comment: try http://127.0.0.1:8080/repository/project

Comment: Sorry because I'm using VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN together so I thinking VisualSVN as the server.. :) By the way are you also using both of them?

Comment: @Eugen: As i said in the post, the link doesnot work. And the error is logical, because right files can only be accessed via repo-browser.

- Not both of them. I said, i am only using Tortoise SVN.

Comment: I've edited your question and added the `http://` prefix to URLs, assuming it was just a formatting issue. If you were actually omitting `http://`, well, that was the problem :)

Comment: Are you stuck with SVN? Why not use git? Its much faster and easy to set up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this link dude [Work with Visual SVN Server & Tortoise SVN](http://rajibmahmud.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/work-with-visual-svn-server-tortoise-svn/). This is step by step procedure how to install Visual SVN Server + Tortoise SVN Client Application and how to configure them. 
For the Tortoise Url in my case I'm using `https://fullcomputername/svn/NameofYourRepository` or could find it in your Visual SVN Server Manager. The link that I provide to you will guide you how to find it. :)
It's Highly Recommended to use TortoiseSVN with VisualSVN because they work well together see VisualSVN Testimonials [here](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/testimonials/).

Comment: Actually i wanted to do it, without using Visual SVN installed. Is their any way ?

Comment: It's Highly Recommended to use TortoiseSVN with VisualSVN see the link of my updated answer to see the testimonials about VisualSVN.

Comment: Highly recommended by whom, exactly? Testimonials on VisualSVN's website are by definition biased; there is no requirement to use the two together, and there is no negative impact by *not* using VisualSVN with TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Are you stuck with SVN? Why not use git? It'

Comment: @alroc sorry I just based my statement from the testimonials of known programmers like Jeff Atwood and Peter Gekko. And I didn't said its a requirement its just a recommendation based from the experience of known programmers. If you feel dont like it its ok. I just answered from what I believe is right because I'm also using them both. If you believe the other way then you could answer on your own. Anyway you are right that its not a requirement and there is no negative impact of not using them both. This is just a suggestion. The end decision is still on the user.. :)

Comment: Wow. Why so flame, guys? :) @bot, you point to a VisualSVN **Visual Studio extension** testimonials, so it's a bit confusing. Please check LazyBadger's answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Creating repository inside web-space **does not convert this repository automagically** to be http-served by Apache
2. Single Apache instance **can be** ordinary web-server and backend for SVN|WebDAV at the same time

You must to read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) and configure your  Apache in order to have http-repositories